# How do I reset nextProps.arbitraryValue once I have used it?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am working on a react-native project.

I have Component A that calls Component B.

When screen B is finished doing work, it calls:

```
NavigationActions.pop({refresh: {workComplete: true}})
```

And on Screen A, I have the following code:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.workComplete) {
      window.alert('work was completed');
    }
  }
```

However, the props.workComplete stays set, and I'm not sure how to unset it, so I keep getting an alert when props are changed in this component.

How can I reset that property value?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by unset, but this will be called everytime props change and since workComplete is set to true, it will constantly alert you. You can have workComplete as a state value and do something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.workComplete !== this.state.workComplete) {
      this.setState({ workComplete: true }, () => window.alert('work was completed'));
    }
  }
```